# What to do when no errors and error-reporting enabled?

Tags: php, error-reporting

Im lost here, closed few files and clicked yes on save all and now page wont load and error_reporting(1); its in all documents... No erors given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your error isn't a syntax error, you can manually debug by placing `die('test');` in various areas of your code to see if that portion executes.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to turn on the display of errors, so at the top of your file add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: Thank god, i went for a walk. Ill try and let you know

Comment: *(tipp)* using -1 instead of `E_ALL` will enable all error reporting including `E_STRICT` and any error levels PHP might introduce in future versions of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on error_reporting and display_errors in your php.ini file. If you have a syntax errror in the script, most likely the script's being killed long before execution could ever reach in the in-script ini_set/error_reporting overrides.

You might want to check the server's error log, as fatal errors generally get sent there if error reporting/display is turned off.

Comment: Depends on what system you're running this on, and what package you installed. Generally on Unix-ish boxes it would be something like /etc/php5/php.ini